# Error con Conectar un archivo a base de datos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

siendo este mi primer post me gustaria postear una duda que me surgio actualmente al desarrollar una tarea para mi Universidad, se trata de conectar un simple Login realizado en HTML mezclado con un poco de PHP y que deberia interactuar con el servicio de base de datos el cual la BD Siendo "ejemplos1 en la celda 1 Nombre,celda 2 PASSWORD, celda 3 EMAIL(Todas siendo de tipo VARCHAR(no sè si realmente importa pero considero que mientras mas informacion se tenga mejor para poder entender el problema.))

```css
<?php include 'clases/usuario.php';
include 'clases/conexion.php';
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$PASSWORD=$_POST["PASSWORD"];
echo "el nombre es:".$nombre."su email es:".$email;
echo "su PASSWORD es:".$PASSWORD;
$conn=new conexion();
$miconexion=$conectar();
$sql="insert into usuario valures(?,?,?)";
$stm=$miconexion->prepare($sql);
$stm->bind("asd", $e, $n, $t, $e=$NuevoUsuario->getEmail(), $n=$NuevoUsuario->getNombre(), $t=$NuevoUsuario->getPassword());
$res=$stm->execute();
echo "El resultado es: $res";
if($stoma->execute()==1) {
  echo" Datos guardados!! XD XD";
}

else {
  echo"se produjo un problema". $stm->error;
}

<?php
   

class Usuario {
  private $nombre;
  private $PASSWORD;
  private $email;
  function __construct($nombre, $PASSWORD, $email) {
    $this->nombre=$nombre;
    $this->PASSWORD=$PASSWORD;
    $this->email=$email;
  }
  function getUsuario() {
    return $this->nombre;
  }
  function getPassword() {
    return $this->PASSWORD;
  }
  function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
  }
  function setUsuario($nombre) {
    $this->nombre=$nombre;
  }
  function setPassword($PASSWORD) {
    $this->PASSWORD=PASSWORD;
  }
  function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email=$email;
  }
}

<?php class conexion {
  private $servidor="localhost";
  private $usuario="root";
  private $password="";
  private $baseDatos="ejemplos1";
  public function conectar() {
    $conexion=mysql_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->password, $this->baseDatos);
    if (!$conexion) //avisa si se conecta si no mata la conexion
    {
      $conexion=FALSE;
    }
    return $conexion;
  }
}

<?php include_once'clases/conexion.php' $conn=new conectar();
if ($conn-> conectar()) {
  echo'Conectado';
}

else echo'No Conectado :(';
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- Website CSS style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">

  <!-- Website Font style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <title>Admin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row main">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title text-center">
          <h1 class="title">Company Name</h1>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-login main-center">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="registrarUsuario.php">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="username" placeholder="Enter your nombre" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="PASSWORD" class="form-control" name="PASSWORD" id="PASSWORD" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group ">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
          </div>
          <div class="login-register">
            <a href="index.php">Login</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: antes del error]

[image: IMG del error]

Comment: Pero, ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: En la Linea " $conn=new conexion(); " no reconoce la conexion a Mysql

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no la reconoce, que mensaje de error aparece?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name mus be a string

Comment: `$miconexion=$conectar();` esto es funcion? o e variable que es???  `mysql_connect` esto ya no se utiliza  es `mysqli_connect` y donde esta la clase `$conn=new conectar()` conectar si solo veo una clase llamada  `conexion`